# Hide keyboard in Webview QML

Tags: keyboard, hide, qml

I am using QML's default webview to open up facebook login page in my program. After filling in the credentials and pressing the sign in button, the virtual keyboard does not close and it is filling half of my screen.

Does anyone know a work around?

I have been following this post https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60161 but apparently it does not do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the workaround in the bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60161#c5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Qt 5.3

I found solution on the web:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32152

And here is my code:

```
TextInput  {
    // ...
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("onAccepted");
        Qt.inputMethod.hide(); // hide the keyboard
    }
}
```